# On differentiability (product of two functions)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given that the product $f(x)\cdot g(x)$ is differentiable at $x_0$, I need to work out what conditions over $f(x)$ guarantee that $g(x)$ is also differentiable at $x_0$.
Note: both $f$ and $g$ are $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

My thoughts so far: Well I can easily come up with conditions that guarantee $g(x)$ is differentiable on $x_0$, for example, if $f(x)$ is constant then $(f\cdot g)'$ will only exist if $g'$ exists. But that's probably not a necessary condition.

I wrote $(f\cdot g)'$ as $ \lim_{h\to 0} \left[f(x_0+h)\cdot\frac{(g(x_0+h)-g(x_0))}{h} +g(x_0)\cdot\frac{(f(x_0+h)-f(x_0))}{h}\right]$ and that gives me a hint that maybe $f(x)$ being differentiable at $x_0$ is sufficient and necessary, but i can't prove it, could anyone please help me out?

Comment: Differentiability of $f$ is not enough. For example, take $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x$ for $x<0$ and $g(x)=2x$ for $x\geq 0$, and work out the derivative of $f\cdot g$ at 0 using left/right derivatives.

Comment: Oh, I got that wrong, thanks for the counterexample. Can't see what should be the necessary condition then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm not seeing the trees for the forest, but to me a 'natural' condition would be that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $f(x_0) \neq 0$. That would make $g$ the quotient of (differentiable at $x_0$) functions $fg$ and $f$, and thus the quotient rule would apply.

The differentiability part for $f$ at $x_0$ is necessary if $g(x_0) \neq 0$, with a similar reason.

As has been remarked in the comments, if $f(x_0)=0$, then $g$ may or may not be differentiable (at $x_0$) even if $f$ is.

Answer (score 0):

You must use that 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(x_0+h)-g(x_0)}{h}=g'(x_0)$$ and
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=f'(x_0)$$ 
And $$\lim_{h\to 0}f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)$$ and $$\lim_{h\to 0}g(x_0)=g(x_0)$$

Comment: I'm sorry, doctor, but how can this help on this problem? Since I don't know if the individual limits exist I can't break them apart in two other limits, right?

Comment: Given is that $$(fg)$$ is differentiable in $$x_0$$

Comment: see also here https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-prove-the-product-rule-of-differentiation